# Json data from Rest service documentation has slash in its keys

Tags: javascript, json, object

Im trying to build a dashboard of apis that are used within my company to centralize and give examples and documentation. The data that I need to display has / slashes in it and cant figure out how to step into it.

```
data.paths/api/IDCard??
```

I tried escaping the slashes, I tried converting the data, I tried using ./
'/' not sure what else to do

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "v1",
    "title": "IDCardRequest"
  },
  "host": "fasoa-prd1.corp.wpsic.com",
  "basePath": "/IDCardRequest",
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/api/IDCard": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "IDCard"
        ],
        "operationId": "IDCard_Get",
        "consumes": [],
        "produces": [
          "application/json",
          "text/json",
          "application/xml",
          "text/xml"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
              "type": "object"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "IDCard"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

keep getting undefined. I want the value for the specific key that I am referencing

Comment: Hi Charles, Welcome to StackOverflow! Could please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve? It would also be great if you could share what you have done so far

Comment: I did share what I've tried so far, it is in the post??  I need the data inside the get and post keys to display for documentation similar to how it looks on swagger

Comment: What language are you using to access the particular data ? Is it javascript? cos you are saying u are getting 'undefined'

Answer (score 1):

You can reach property **data.paths["/api/IDCard"]** like this.

There is a sample here.

```
var value = {
  "paths": {
    "/api/IDCard": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "IDCard"
        ],
        "operationId": "IDCard_Get",
        "consumes": [],
        "produces": [
          "application/json",
          "text/json",
          "application/xml",
          "text/xml"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
              "type": "object"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "IDCard"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(value.paths["/api/IDCard"].get.tags)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the above object is in `data`,Try accessing it as follows

```
dataInsideGet  = data.paths["/api/IDCard"]["get"]
dataInsidePost  = data.paths["/api/IDCard"]["post"]

console.log(dataInsideGet) // Your desired object
```

Whenever you have Object keys with special characters, you should be using the array notation to access the objects.

More about Property Accessors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

Hope it helps!